# Google place api dropdown touch not working in mobile (Meteor framework)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3

I'm facing really weird issue on a meteor App. I used google maps api for location dropdown autocomplete. It works perfectly on pc & android mobile.

But can't select the dropdown listed location on windows phone & iphone.

I've searched about this and found many solutions on stack-overflow but none works for me.

You can check it here : http://dev.urbanchefs.ae/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I just removed "**fastclick**" from the meteor package list. Now it's working.